# LINQ query complex join problem

Tags: linq

So I was trying to convert a SQL into LINQ query

the logic is:

```
  JOIN SalesPeriod SP1 
  ON
     SP1.SalesPeriodId = SE1.SalesPeriodId AND SP1.SalePeriodId = .....(XML stuff)
```

but it keeps complaining the types on both sides of equals statement don't match

Any ideas?

Note: I declared b and d because it doesn't accept anonymous type members
      and I tested two equal conditions separately and they both work

thanks

```
   join SP1 in fentities.SalesPeriods
                on new { SE1.SalesPeriodId, b = XDocument.Load(MI.Body).Element("ns:Transfer").Element("ns:ReceivedBy").Element("ns:Id").FirstNode.ToString() }
                equals new { SP1.SalesPeriodId, d = SP1.SalesPeriodId.ToString() }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, they're not the same (compatible) types.  The first key has a `SalesPeriodId` of type whatever, and `b` of type string.  The second key has a `SalesPeriodId` of type whatever (probably the same as the first's), and `d` of type string.  You can't compare these to eachother.  It *must* have the same properties of the same types declared in the same order.  Just pick one of the names `b` or `d` and use that name.

```
...
join SP1 in fentities.SalesPeriods
    on new { SE1.SalesPeriodId, b = XDocument.Load(MI.Body).Element("ns:Transfer").Element("ns:ReceivedBy").Element("ns:Id").FirstNode.ToString() }
    equals new { SP1.SalesPeriodId, b = SP1.SalesPeriodId.ToString() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two anonymous types do not match, `b` & `d` to be specific.. try aligning the signatures..

```
join SP1 in fentities.SalesPeriods
            on new { SE1.SalesPeriodId, b = XDocument.Load(MI.Body).Element("ns:Transfer").Element("ns:ReceivedBy").Element("ns:Id").FirstNode.ToString() }
            equals new { SP1.SalesPeriodId, b = SP1.SalesPeriodId.ToString() }
```

In that example both anonymous objects will have the same property definitions (`SalesPeriodId` and `b`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't stuck on putting complete join condition into 'ON' clause. Split condition on two parts, put one of them into 'ON' clause and another into 'WHERE' clause.

```
    join SP1 in fentities.SalesPeriods
            on SE1.SalesPeriodId equals SP1.SalesPeriodId        
    where XDocument.Load(MI.Body).Element("ns:Transfer").Element("ns:ReceivedBy").Element("ns:Id").FirstNode.ToString() == SP1.SalesPeriodId.ToString()
```